# How can I add y-axis vertical line to the chart bar between data-1 and data-2 in given code

Tags: chart.js

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("barChart").getContext('2d');
var barChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Property-1", "Property-2", "Property-3", "Property-4", "Property-5", "Property-6", "Property-7", "Property-8", "Property-9", "Property-10", "Property-11", "Property-12", "Property-13", "Property-13"],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'data-1',
      data: [99, 1900, 300, 1700, 2500, 2400, 700, 230, 320, 550, 1600, 1700, 2100, 2300],
      backgroundColor: "rgba(244,162,97)"
    }, {
      label: 'data-2',
      data: [2000, 290, 500, 500, 200, 300, 100, 235, 329, 560, 1700, 1800, 2200, 2400],
      backgroundColor: "rgba(141, 137, 202)"
    }]
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 15px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<main class="container">
  <div>
    <canvas id="barChart"></canvas>
  </div>
</main>
```

Hello there,
As I am using chartjs first time, can anyone resolve the issue.
How can I add y-axis vertical line to the chart bar between data-1 and data-2 in given code.
Reference image attached.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If what you want is to shift the vertical grid lines so that they pass through the center of each bar group, I haven't found an easy solution for the old version `2.1.4` you linked to. Are you tied to that version? In modern versions of chart.js one can move the tick positions and thus the associated grid lines in the [scale callbacks](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/#callbacks), see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1jneu57L/).

Comment: Great. Thanks for your response buddy. 
How can I center align the labels below the vertical grid, like in attached image.

Comment: I looked back on it and I realise the initial solution I proposed was not ideal - it didn't work well for the case when labels were skipped. It turns out it's enough to set `scales.x.grid.offset: true` ([docs ref](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html#grid-line-configuration))to move the grid lines in the middle of the group, see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0psf2tcy/) .

Comment: Thanks allot Sir, Its working as expected.